# How can I access unaligned, volatile memory efficiently?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

I have a memory buffer of a serialized object, with a uint32_t in it.  The uint32_t could easily be at an odd address.  Also, another thread could be writing to the buffer; I can detect this later and throw away my results if it could have happened.

My question is: how can I read the data efficiently (a single movl instruction) on x86_64 without using undefined behavior?

```
uint32_t read_int(const volatile void *ptr) {
     ... what goes here so the generated code is "movl (%rdi), %eax"?
}
```

The traditional way to read unaligned data is with memcpy(), but passing a volatile pointer to it is UB.

I can write my own memcpy replacement that's a simple loop that copies byte-by-byte, but then the compiler assumes I need to read each byte in order and won't optimize it into a single movl.

I can cast the pointer to CV uint32_t *, but that's an unaligned read which is UB.

So, what are my options?

Comment: Why is the pointer volatile? It won't help with threading.

Comment: `volatile` is not an appropriate method of thread synchronization. Your program is UB unless you use atomics or a mutex.

Comment: I'm using optimistic concurrency control: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control .  If the value is changed out from under me, the value is unspecified (not undefined), and I'll detect it later and throw away the results.

Comment: Can you read to `uint64_t` and shift?

Comment: @imreal How can I read to uint64_t?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean in the title by "Volatile."  If it's just memory that is accessed and possibly changed by other threads then it's not volatile. Volatile, in C11 parlance, means that the memory is subject to change to or from things outside of the program like memory mapped IO. If it's only changed by other threads then it isn't volatile.

Comment: @MartinC.Martin `uint32_t` regardless of the unalignment will fit in a `uint64_t`, something like `uint64_t a = *(volatile uint64_t*)(ptr - k); a <<= m;`

Comment: @doug I mean the `volatile` keyword in C++.  The standard says that reads of `volatile` data can't be re-ordered or duplicated, that is, they're treated as having a visible side-effect for the purposes of optimization.  It doesn't actually talk about the data changing or where that change would come from, although that's why people use it of course.

Comment: @imreal intersting idea.  I can't get the optimizer to get rid of the 64 bit read and the shift though.  I'd really like it to optimize down to just a `movl`.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I have a hunch that what you are asking for cannot be expressed in standard C++. I would be happy to be mistaken.

Comment: @MartinC.Martin have you profiled your program and are sure that it is absolutely necessary? Premature optimization is the root of all evil :)

Comment: @user2079303 : I suspect you're right.  :)

Comment: @imreal Its probably not a bottleneck, but I'm looking to learn the bigger rule of thumb, e.g. in the non-volatile case I just remember to use memcpy() and that the compiler will optimize it, so I don't need to choose between correctness and efficiency.  Here I'm trying to learn what the equivalent is, it seems I do have to choose.  :(

Comment: While volatile will stop reordering of code, it doesn't guarantee the cpu won't in hardware. Atomics do. Volatiles can be used for signaling though.